# cv.glmnet Ridge Regression lambda.min = lambda.1se?

Tags: r, lambda, regression, cross-validation, glmnet

I'm currently running a ridge regression in R using the `glmnet` package, however, I recently ran into a new problem and was hoping for some help in interpreting my results. My data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hpxu3t0vqkrzfgf/AAB6F-yMYMfuI5E__gfDuW6sa?dl=0

My data consists of a 26531x428 observation matrix `x` and a 26531x1 response vector `y`. I am attempting to determine the optimal value of `lambda.min`, and when I run the code

`> lambda=cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y,weights=weights,alpha=0,nfolds=10,standardize=FALSE)`

I get

`$lambda.min
[1] 2.123479
$lambda.1se
[1] 619.0054`

which are results I would expect. However, I would like to add a slight tweak to this regression. I have prior knowledge of each of my 428 coefficients, and instead of shrinking each coefficient towards 0, as is the default with ridge regression, I would like to shrink each coefficient towards a specific value other than 0. After reaching out to Dr. Trevor Hastie, one of the creators of `glmnet`, he told me that this could be achieved by running the same code after substituting `y` with `y2`, where `y2 = y - x%*%d` and `d` is a 428x1 vector of coefficient priors. He said to then add `d` to my new coefficients, which would give me my prior-informed coefficients. After rerunning the code

`> lambda=cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y2,weights=weights,alpha=0,nfolds=10,standardize=FALSE)`

I unfortunately get

`$lambda.min
[1] 220.3026
$lambda.1se
[1] 220.3026`

The results of `plot(lambda)` look like this
[image: lambda plot]

Does anyone know why `glmnet` can't find a suitable `lambda.min`? Could it be because my vector of priors contains estimates that are too far off? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think it is better suited to receiving statistical advice; i have voted to move ot to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Actually , just noticed http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174557/cv-glmnet-ridge-regression-lambda-min-lambda-1se

Comment: Could you please provide your data (including the coefficient of priors) so that I can reproduce this issue?

Comment: @tguzella The files can be downloaded here, let me know if this works for you https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hpxu3t0vqkrzfgf/AAB6F-yMYMfuI5E__gfDuW6sa?dl=0